# BigQuery - DML Suport on Partitioned Tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to be able to patch some table data, in a partitioned table, via DML (e.g update a column from a -> b, delete a row...etc, the usual).

However I get an error in the BQ console that this is not supported for partitioned tables.

Is there a timeframe for this pretty fundamental support?

How are others working around this if at all?

Thanks!

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36383555

Comment: thanks elliot I looked but must have originally missed this - hoping this will be addressed somepoint in the very near future as its quite painful to not be able to patch so bad data.

Comment: Thanks for commenting!

Comment: We (from the BigQuery team) understand--please star that feature request to receive an update as soon as the feature is available. Thanks!

Comment: have done that thanks heaps Elliot!

Answer (score 1):

DML with partitioned tables has been supported (in beta) as of March 2018! https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables